# Limit of Matrix functions

Tags: limits, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ and $B(t)$ dependent on parameter $t$ be $n\times n$ matrices. $B(t)$ is positive definite for all $t>0$.  Also, let $C$ be an $n \times m$ ($m<n$) matrix. We know that $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1}{t^2}B(t) = B_0$, where $B_0$ is positive semi-definite and $B_0C=0$. $A$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite such that $A=X^{\top}B_0X$, where $X$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix. Show that $\lim_{t \to 0}(A+B(t))^{-1}B(t)C=0$?

Thanks

Comment: $(A+B(t))^{-1}B(t)C=t^{2}(A+B(t))^{-1}(t^{-2}B(t))C.$ By assumption, $t^{-2}B(t)C\rightarrow B_{0}C=0.$ Can you show that $t^{2}(A+B(t))^{-1}$ is bounded as $t\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: The problem is that $A$ and $B_0$ are not invertible. So, it can not be shown that $t^2(A+B(t))^{−1}$ is bounded. However, $(A+B(t))^{−1}B(t)$ is always bounded for $t>0$.

Comment: I'm not totally convinced by your argument, since $t^{2}(A+B(t))^{-1}$ is only unbounded if $(A+B(t))^{-1}$ becomes large fast enough relative to $t^{2},$ which is not clear. For instance, if $A=0$ and $B(t)=tI,$ then $(A+B(t))^{-1}=t^{-1}I,$ and $t^{2}(A+B(t))^{-1}=tI,$ which is bounded as $t\rightarrow 0.$

Comment: The example you provide does not satisfy the assumption $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t^2}B(t)=B_0$. I think $(A+B(t))^{−1}$ can become large fast enough relative to $t^2$ depending to the order of the matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We assume $C\not= 0$. Since $m<n$, $C^T$ is not one to one and there is $x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ s.t. $C^Tx=0$; then let $B_0=xx^T$ and $B(t)=t^2B_0+tI_n$.

We choose $A=0$ and the considered expression is $C$, that does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your example by a little change is correct. (correction: $(B(t)=t^2B0+t^3I_n$).Matrix  A can not be chosen freely. I revised the problem with additional assumption on $A$.